# Using apt-get under custom kernel

Tags: apt, kernel

I've compiled a custom kernel, and it installs as `linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-26-generic`. Now any time I try to get a package using `apt` I'm told that I have unmet dependencies:

```
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic but it is not 
going to be installed
```

Trying `--fix-broken install` threatens to remove `linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-26-generic`.

(The packages I've tried are `blktrace`, `equivs`, `expect` and others).

How can I get around this?

The kernel was compiled by cloning the `eoan` repository, making a minor change and building using `debian/rules ...`. It was installed via `dpkg` but I had to remove the running kernel first to avoid a conflict.

Comment: This means you did many things wrong and the question is very unclear. Why the custom kernel has the same version as the kernel provided in Ubuntu repositories. That's a bad practice. What is "a package" you are getting using apt that depends on `linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic`? Please [edit] your question and explain what did you compile and how and what exact commands you run with their output.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added the relevant info. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post output of `sudo apt install blktrace`? It doesn't depend on any kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6. You're right. It's a general unmet dependency. I've added the output.

Comment: So the package does install? It is not wrong that `linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic` will be removed. It is a meta package pointing to a signed kernel. That won't remove the kernel itself.

Comment: @Pilot6 The packages will not install. It just fails and notes the issue, suggesting `--fix-broken install`. If I run it, it says it will remove `linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-26-generic` and install `linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic`.

Comment: You'd better build with a custom version. Do `dch -i` and update `config` to something like `5.3.0-26~blabla`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103721/discussion-between-reinstate-monica-and-pilot6).